# Filezilla stopped working on upgrade to 16.04

Tags: icons

I recently updated my Ubuntu installation on PC from 15.10 to 16.04 and now I can't run Filezilla. (All other apps are OK as far as I can tell.)
When I go to Dash and click on the Filezilla icon, the icon appears in the Launcher, the hard drive appears to fetch some files for about 8 seconds, and then the icon in the Launcher disappears and nothing happens. 
I have removed and re-installed Filezilla (several times!), but the problem persists.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to run it from terminal by entering `filezilla` and post eventual error messages output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/766593/filezilla-not-working-after-upgrade-from-ubuntu-15-10-to-ubuntu-16-04/766614

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot start FileZilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798031/cannot-start-filezilla)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had just deleted the file `~/.config/filezilla/filezilla.xml` and it worked.

I think something's wrong with the old configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You can just rename the config file of FileZilla, for it please execute the command in terminal:

```
mv ~/.config/filezilla/filezilla.xml old-filezilla.xml
```

Don't worry with the loss of configured, because the FileZilla make a new configure file with the old configured and you don't lose your configures