# FILEZILLA not working after upgrade from ubuntu 15.10 to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, filezilla

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 15.10 (x64 version) and now I am unable to run FileZilla.  There is some hard drive activity and then nothing.

When I open a terminal and type "Filezilla" I get the following error:

```
Reading locale option from /home/james/.filezilla/filezilla.xml
(filezilla:5532): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed
(filezilla:5532): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed
(filezilla:5532): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed
(filezilla:5532): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed
(filezilla:5532): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed
(filezilla:5532): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed
(filezilla:5532): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have checked my system log and it has this line:

```
May  2 21:56:55 JamesPC kernel: [ 3133.290205] filezilla[5532]: segfault at 140 ip 00007f8a3152dbc6 sp 00007ffda52e17e0 error 4 in libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0.2.0[7f8a3102d000+5f9000]
```

Comment: Possibly related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/filezilla/+bug/1567133

Please try removing the `.filezilla` directory within your home directory, then run FileZilla again.

Answer (score 6):

Problem with version 3.15 but solved in 3.20.

1. Backup your config files, they can be located in `~/.config/filezilla` or `~/.filezilla`
2. Download the latest FileZilla version from [here](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client)
3. Run:

   ```
   tar -xvf FileZilla_3.20.1_x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.bz2
   cp -rp Filezilla3/bin/* /usr/bin/
   ```

Then, the output of `filezilla --version` should be:

```
    FileZilla 3.20.1 official build, compiled on 2016-08-03
```

4. If you want you can create a launcher do this:

   ```
   wget http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/filezilla-icon-6.png
   mkdir -p ~/Filezilla
   mv filezilla-icon-6.png ~/Filezilla/filezilla.png
   echo '[Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Name=Filezilla 3.20.1
   Comment=Filezilla easy FTP transfer
   Exec=/usr/bin/filezilla
   Icon=~/Filezilla/filezilla.png
   Categories=Application;Development;FTP;network
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Terminal=0
   ' > ~/.local/share/applications/filezilla.desktop
   ```
5. Copy your config to the new config folder `~/.config/filezilla`

Answer (score 3):

As per the comment from Nick Weinberg I removed the .filezilla directory within the home directory and it now works ("sudo rm -rf .filezilla")

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `.filezilla` directory works **temporarily**. The problem comes back after a few uses. Removing the directory is necessary each time it reoccurs.

FYI, the second time I had this issue there was no `.filezilla` directory. I had to remove `.config/filezilla` instead

Answer (score 0):

I tried first solution by @Roben and it worked temporarily

Then i tried second solutions by removing entire directory from

```
home/.config/filezilla
```

which also works. But the problem was old saved details about sites were lost. Not good !!

So i then tried removing just one file from `home/.config/filezilla/filezilla.xml`

So removing just

> filezilla.xml

worked without removing the old details.
Since sitemanager.xml details are not altered here.

Works for me without damaging anything.

Comment: One more solution here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/798031/cannot-start-filezilla/912664#912664