# Filezilla: Error loading queue

Tags: 18.10, ftp, filezilla

I'm on Ubuntu 18.10 and Filezilla has been giving me a lot of trouble.  After installing it through the app manager (out of date version), shell (out of date version), and the website's .tar.bz2 file; I have found that only the file works.

But now I'm getting an *Error loading queue* and my login information isn't being accepted (like with the out of date versions).  I don't know exactly what's wrong and the troubleshooting is getting frustrating, but I would at least like to uninstall the version I got through shell and see how well that works.  The problem is that I don't know how.  Any help?

Comment: Did you uninstall the program from software center before installing it from TAR file? Do you remember what you did to install it from TAR File? Here is how to uninstall the FileZilla version installed from Ubuntu software center and command line : `sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l | grep filezilla | awk '{print $2}')` - To uninstall the TAR file version, simply revert what was done to install it

Comment: Perhaps this older post might be of assistance: https://askubuntu.com/a/798065/57576